# How to test Capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a script that use Capybara to publish links in Google+. I would like to have tests to cover this functionality. Usually Capybara is using as a tool for writing Integration tests. In may case i need to test Capybara itself.

I see 3 possible ways:

- stub capybara's method (but in this case i test nothing but just stubbed methods)
- test capybara agains saved HTML/JS page (that will help me understand that i did not break anything during refactoring)
- do not test at all (no comments here)

Have you ever faced such a problem?

Comment: I faced this problem and went with option 3. Option 1 makes no sense, though depending on your use case, option 2 may work (it certainly didn't work for my use case).

Answer (score 1):

If you register different drivers for your app and your test code, possibly manage the sessions manually depending on how you're using it in your app,  and make sure you're careful with Capybaras setting's you should be able to go with option 2.  You have to be careful with Capybaras settings because most of them are global so changing them for your tests will also change them for your app.